# CSVDE Export has blank values in userAccountControl column

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to export users and most of them are showing a blank value for the userAccountControl field.  I need this to show what users are active and what users are inactive.  Any idea why this is so?

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to run the command line shell as Administrator.  It took me 15 minutes to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes running powershell as administrator worked, it is wierd because you would never expect it to be this problem because it was exporting some values and not the others. Great Catch Peter.